# How do I internationalize input?

Tags: perl, translation, gettext

I have three variations of this question in increasing difficulty. All questions assume gettext prompts looking for a single letter response. I am currently writing in perl, but a answer in C is acceptable as I have and can write XS modules. you can assume there are no input method problems, and that the locale variables are set correctly.

1. So, let us say that I have a program that asks `gettext("are you sure you want to do that (Yes/No)?")` and it has been translated into Spanish (`... (Si/No)?"`), french, and valspeak (`... (No problemo/Stop right there)?"` How can I tell if the letter I receive from input means yes or no?
2. Let us assume that we are displaying a menu with a question like `gettext("Which install procedure do you want?")` with options like `gettext("(N)ovice")`, `gettext("(I)ntermediate")`, `gettext("(E)xpert")`, and `gettext("(A)utomated")`. In English I would accept `[niea]`. What do I accept if the user speaks Russian? or Chinese? or Swahili?
3. My actual project involves translating boot menus from a general format to formats that work with multiple bootloaders. Given that for each menu entry I have a set of key value pairs (menu text, hot key, and action among others) I see three possible ways of generating menus in languages I do not speak.

   1. (easy) Have the whole menu translated. Advantages are that the file is simple, the action and related keys can be ignored, no work to implement. Disadvantages are that there are no translation tools to help with this and languages may get out of sync.
   2. (medium) Add language specific key values like menu_fr, hotkey_fr, menu_ch... Advantages are that it is simple to implement and that everything is right there. Disadvantages are again that sync issues arise.
   3. (unknown) Use gettext with the main menu in English. Advantages include plenty of translator tools, established workflow, menu entries are not difficult to implement, and since I am already using gettext for progress messages most of the implementation is fairly straightforward. The disadvantage is that I do not know how to recognize hot-keys.

What is the best solution?

Comment: Automated translation is really not at the point where you can use that as your primary mechanism. No idea what differences exists between #1 or #2, or what you mean by "sync issues".

Comment: @ikegami gettext does not do machine translation, it allows for translators to not need to work with code. As for sync, when there is a change that affects a message, that message needs retranslated. #1 is simpler than #2 in that it is only concerned with Boolean answers.

Comment: I went from not understanding #1 and #2 to also not understanding #3 since I thought that was automated translation

Comment: There is actually no way to *completely* automate what you're trying to do. A crude approach would be to ask your translators to use some kind of format that you can then parse to check the answer. E.g.: "Continue [y/N] ?" could become "Continue [\\1y/\\0N] ?" and you have to parse the string knowing that the letter after \\1 is yes and the one after \\0 is no. Yes, I agree that is quite ugly and requires some cooperation from translators, but there's not much of a choice. Also, you have to be careful when using multi-byte languages.

Answer (score 0):

After much reading, I believe I have found the answer: the context variants of the `gettext` calls like `pgettext`.

```
echo gettext("Which install procedure do you want?");
echo pgettext("Which install procedure do you want?", "Novice");
echo pgettext("Which install procedure do you want?", "Intermediate");
echo pgettext("Which install procedure do you want?", "Expert");
echo pgettext("Which install procedure do you want?", "Automated");
ans=getc();
if(ans == pgettext("Which install procedure do you want?|Novice","N") ){
    do novice;
}elseif(ans == pgettext("Which install procedure do you want?|Intermediate","I") ){
. . .
```